# Does UIView based is optimized compared to navigation based?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I got a new project to do which is UIViewController based but previously one of my senior told me that UINavigationController based project is much good compared to UIViewController based since in navigation based there is pushing and poping of views can be handled so safer in memory point of view but if it is view based we need to use addsubview and removefromsubview there is possibility of sandwiching of views it may cause memory leaks.
But now in my new project according to design i need to use UIViewController based project only so i'm feared how to handle navigation of views, is there any other way to handle this? or whatever assumptions i'm having is not write?

Any help is appreciated in advance.Thank You.

Comment: If you logically need different levels of navigation, then navigate.

Answer (score 0):

Those projects are just templates. There is nothing stopping you from using a UINavigationController within a project originally created as a single UIView project.

The different project templates simply start you off with different files at the beginning. If you started off with a single UIView project, and decide you need a UITabBar, you can easily do so without "AddSubView".